# Is there an out-of-the-box way to create a custom non-convex polygon in three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

Does Three.js offer an out-of-the-box way to create custom non-convex polygon, or do I have to use `THREE.Geometry` and set faces manually? I'm guessing that `ShapeGeometry` has something to do with this, but I can't find either documentation or examples.

Comment: I don't know three.js, but it might be helpful to know that this problem is called [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'm sure that somebody did this already and optimized code. I don't want to break down the open door.

PS Thank you for edit also.